# How sum product in excel?

Tags: excel

[image]
[image]

How sum total Number of Product in Sheet 1 to Total Column in Sheet 2?

Comment: Are you asking how to do it in Excel, or via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Sheet2**, Use following formulas:

For A, In the cell B2, paste below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!A2:A7="A"),Sheet1!C2:C7)
```

For B, In the cell B3, paste below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!A2:A7="B"),Sheet1!C2:C7)
```

For C, In the cell B4, paste below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!A2:A7="C"),Sheet1!C2:C7)
```

Output is as below in Sheet2:

```
       | A     |   B
----------------------
1      |Product|  Total
-----------------------
2      | A     |   4
----------------------
3      | B     |  11
----------------------
4      | C     |  1
```

**EDIT:**

Use below formula in cell B2 of sheet 2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=A2),Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7)
```

And drag and drop it till the end of your projects list (If the list is known). If list is unknown, then it is better to use a pivot table.

**EDIT AGAIN:**
For using pivot,

1. Menu --> Insert --> Pivot Table
2. Select Table or Range --> Enter `Sheet1!$A$1:$C$7`
3. Choose Where you want it to be placed --> `New Worksheet`
4. For Row Labels --> Choose `Product`
5. For Sum of Values --> Choose `Quantity`

Comment: @Chinaisthepirates: Refer the Edited Formula. It is generic and can be dragged till end of list.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your goal by generating a pivot table like shown [here](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-summary-functions.html) This is more generic than the solution provided by Nisha.

However, this is not a coding question. You'll be better off when using an excel forum in the future.

Update: You can also find a tutorial [here](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel). You can use any tutorial concerning pivot tables and that are not being censored in your country ;-)

Comment: your link:Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /excel-pivot-table-summary-functions.html on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: From where do you access the site? Do you work in china?

Comment: you site from china. China doesn't allow access from vietnam.

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be a PivotTable but another alternative would be to copy Sheet1 into Sheet2, sort there by Product then select entire range and with DATA > Outline - Subtotal At each change in: `Product`, Use function: `Sum` and Add subtotal to: `NUMBER`.

Filter to show only Product column contains `tot` to suppress rows other than subtotals/Grand Total.